# How to upload short videos (10-15 secs) from an Android App to AWS using Node.js?

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-encoding

Once the application gives me a `GET` Request for the file along with the video,
what should we use in our Node.JS file to correctly optimize the video, compress/encode the video in which format and minimize the uploading time for end user?

I understand the file needs to be `asynchronously` uploaded. But what should be my backend systems be designed like?

We'll be using `AWS`, and `Mongo DB`. So all the videos will be uploaded to `S3 Bucket`. Is this the best practice?

Basic requirement is I am trying to make the uploading video as much scalable and concurrent for multiple users to upload video.

Are there any kind of best practices or tutorial for the kind of video formatting and uploading in `Node.JS` we are looking for?

Comment: what are you using to upload in node? Either http or tcp ?